# widget size ration tablet

Tags: android, widget, size, tablet

I'm using this widget:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ankidroid_widget_small_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:focusable="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_small">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:focusable="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="4dip"
android:clickable="false">
<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_due"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_number"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/widget_progress_frame"
    android:layout_below="@+id/widget_due"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/widget_due"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="5dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:padding="1dip"> 
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/widget_progress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
    <!--<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/widget_progress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="#ff595a"/>-->
</FrameLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_eta"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_time"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ankidroid_widget_small_finish_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_small_finish"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:clickable="false">
   </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

works perfectly on normal handsets (sgs 9000) but on my table (galaxy tab 10.1) it looks somehow malformed (significantly broader than it should be). Is it possible that the rectangle width height ratios are different on larger screen sizes?